# How to remove keyboard icon from keyboard layout indicator (to leave just the language abbr. alone)?

Tags: gnome, 10.10, keyboard, panel, input-language

I'd like to remove a keyboard icon, so replacing "[###] USA" as keyboard layout indicator to just "En", an English or American flag, or "USA" at least. How can I achieve this?

UPDATE: When I've clicked to remove e-mail icon from the bar, keyboard language indication has disappeared also, and now I only see that useless keyboard icon, and don't see what language is selected now :-(

I use Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to [monotasker's solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4679/how-to-remove-keyboard-icon-from-keyboard-layout-indicator-to-leave-just-the-lan/8793#8793), here's exact steps how to easily get flags instead of *keyboard icon + abbreviation*:

1. in `gconf-editor`, check `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/indicator/showFlags`
2. install set of flags using `sudo apt-get install famfamfam-flag-png`
3. make a softlink: `ln -s /usr/share/flags/countries/16x11 ~/.icons/flags`

In the next login, you should see flags in indicator applet.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, but the given answer is not exactly the answer of the question. Yes, the solution works for the INDICATOR applet, but what we would like to have is a solution for the NOTIFICATION area. For some reason now the keyboard indicator there can't find the icons, other than the default crappy keyboard picture.
In addition I use the connected application 'Typing Monitor', which also doesn't show icon in the NOTIFICATION bar. I am not sure if they are going to fix it officially https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/623435/comments/14

Answer (score 4):

The solution here is to turn on the "show flags" option and install some flag image files.

I've posted a pack of SVG language flags (along with instructions for installing and enabling them) [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+Dark+Panel?content=133910)  (for dark panels) and [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+and+Elementary?content=133726) (for light panels).

The light-panel version looks best with Faenza or Elementary iconsets, but is also not bad with ubuntu-mono-light. The dark panel version is really best suited for Faenza. If there's enough interest, I can create another set to match ubuntu-mono-dark. The gnome-look.org pages include instructions for installing the sets.

And if I've missed your language, let me know the code and I'll add it to the set.

Answer (score 4):

[Solved]

To completely remove the keyboard indicator we need to change one byte in the `/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-2.0/libkeyboard.so` file.

1. Make a backup of `libkeyboard.so` file.
2. Open the file with root privileges through any hex editor (I use Bless).
3. Search for the byte signature `FF 83 F8 01 0F`

   `FF 83 F8 01 0F = if (g_slist_length (current_kbd_config.layouts_variants) > 1)`
4. Change 01 to 02

   `FF 83 F8 02 0F`
5. Save the file. (this should be the new contents of the file)

   `FF 83 F8 02 0F = if (g_slist_length (current_kbd_config.layouts_variants) > 2)`

If you have less than 3 keyboard layouts, icon will be not shown. After this, you need to reload `gnome-settings-daemon`, you can use `reboot` for this.

Comment: worked perfectly for me. Even though i have version 3 (gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/libkeyboard.so) and the sequence is found twice. I changed both of them

Answer (score 1):

I think icon will be removed from indicator in release. So just wait 2 weeks. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-ubuntu/+bug/620331 for further information. And note "Fix commited" status of that bug.

EDIT: Try /apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/keyboard/active=false for now. Also, install xneur (auto-layout switcher for X).

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial on how to change the keyboard layout indicator so it displays country flags:

http://elementaryos.org/docs/user-guide/customizing/language-layout-flags

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Thank you.